# UIPopoverController size changes when new controller is push on navigation controller set in UIPopover controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have below issue with `UIPopoverController` and `UINavigationController`:

I have created one `UINavigationController` with one `UITableViewController` in that. Then I have set this `UINavigationController` to `UIPopoverController`.
I have requirement to have square `UIPopoverController` so I used `setPopoverContentSize` of `UIPopoverController`. I also used `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.

Issue is when I launch popover it is shown rectangle. But now when I push another `UITableViewController` by clicking on first `UITableViewController` row then whole popover is displayed with default size what normally we get.

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.
If more detail is required then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` for each view controller you want to push. So for your second `UITableViewController` as well. Hope this helps.